# Обновление данных на pug странице каждую секунду

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

В своем проекте я использую `express, node.js` в качестве серверной части. Для отображения использую шаблонизатор `pug`. Я хотел бы узнать, как я могу передавать новые данные каждую секунду на страницу. Код прикреплю ниже.

P.S. 1. `setInterval` не подходит, так как выдает ошибки. 2. Метод `netInfo.getStats()` выдает новые данные.

```js
app.get('/network', async (req, res)=> {
  try {
    const netInfo = require('./lib/net');
    const netIface = await netInfo.netInterface();
    setInterval(async function() {
      const stats = await netInfo.getStats();
      res.render('network', {
        title: 'Network',
        slogan: 'Get data about ip address, mask and etc.',
        data: {...netIface, ...stats},
      });
    }, 1000);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Несколько раз отрендарить и отдать данные клиенту у тебя точно не получиться. 
После того как express отдал отрендаринную страницу он закроет соеденения.Так ведется работа с протоколом HTTP. Без [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) не обойтись.

В товем случае есть два варианта:
Варинт 1: Создать API который будет возвращать необходимые данные и клиентским скриптом опрашивать это API с каким либо интервалом и обновлять данные на странице.

Пример для сервера

```
app.get('/net-info', (req, res) => {
    const netIface = await netInfo.netInterface();
    const stats = await netInfo.getStats();
    req.send({
       ...netIface,
       ...stats
    });
    res.end();
});
```

Пример для клиента

```
<script>
    setInterval(aync () => {
        const res = await fetch('/net-info');
        const data = await res.json();
        // Найти нужные элементы на странице и обновить их
        // cons el = getElementById('id');
    }, 1000);

</script>
```

[Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Либо.

Вариант 2:

Заморочиться и создать web-socket server который сам сможет отправлять клиенту данные. Опять же без клинтского кода тут не обойтись: необходимо подключиться к web-socket серверу, и по приходу данных обновлять данные на странице.

[Web-sockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

[Одна из библиотек реализующая ws для NodeJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket)

Comment: Как раз сейчас хотел написать ответ на свой вопрос. Начал использовать веб-сокеты для этого и все отлично заработало. Захожу, а тут ответ дали) Спасибо)

Comment: Поэтому буду придерживаться второго варианта